# Immutability and memory usage

Tags: scala, memory, memory-management, immutability

I was expecting extremely small increase in memory usage after adding an element to immutable Seq. Because new reference (`val`) can re-use memory allocate for already created `val` and an additional memory allocation would be required for the new element only. In other words I do not see a necessity for the defensive copy to be created (see here https://users.scala-lang.org/t/inquiry-on-immutabillity-of-objects-and-how-they-affect-memory/2340).

In reality, however, after adding one element memory usage increases to the same amount as creating completely new Seq. Below is a code snippet from the SBT project

```
object obj extends App {

  val n = 1000000

  def usedMem = {
    val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime
    runtime.totalMemory - runtime.freeMemory
  }

  val m1 = usedMem
  
  val ar = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill(n)("hohohohoho")
  val m2 = usedMem
  println ("1 " + (m2-m1))

  val sq = Seq.fill(n)("hohohohoho")
  val m3 = usedMem
  println ("2 " + (m3-m2))

  val ar0 = ar :+ "yo"
  val m4 = usedMem
  println ("3 " + (m4-m3))

  val sq0 = sq :+ "yo"
  val m5 = usedMem
  println ("4 " + (m5-m4))

}
```

In the output we see that memory usage after step 2 and after step 4 increased by almost 24MB. I would expect very small increase after step 4 though.

```
1 4103816
2 23948288
3 4546184
4 23948600
```

Can someone explain this behaviour? Or alternatively how to see that memory is re-used for immutable objects.

Also I was quite surprised that memory usage for ArrayBuffer is much smaller than for Seq (4MB vs 24MB). Would be great to understand this difference as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are not using a proper data structure for the job.

Here: `val sq = Seq.fill(n)("hohohohoho")` you are creating a `Seq` but a `Seq` is an abstract type, and thus it has to pick a concrete implementation. And as of the day of writing such default is usually a `List`

And `Lists` can't share memory when appending, they have to copy everything *(which means it is pretty slow too)*.

Now, what you may do is to use a data structure that is optimized to append, like `Vector` or **cats** `Chain`
You may also use `List` directly and prepend instead of append like:

```scala
val sq = List.fill(n)("hohohohoho")
val sq0 = "yo" :: sq
```

---

*This is one of the reasons why I personally dislike `Seq`, it doesn't provide enough information to do anything useful with it*.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now. Memory cannot be re-used simply because of the way how append works (for any data structure). On a separate note, do you know what is the point of having the methods "::" and ":+" with the same purpose for List?

Comment: @DrYWit _"(for any data structure)"_ that is false, both `Vector` and `Chain` not only reuse memory for appending but also do that on linear time. - _"having the methods "::" and ":+" with the same purpose for List"_ because of the complicated hierarchy the stdlib has, `List` has to inherit the `+:` standard method but it also provides the concrete `::` which only exists for `List`, the same happens with `++` and `:::`; you can use `+:` since it is overridden to just call `::` but I prefer to make it clear that I am using a `List` and nothing else.

Comment: thank you very much for the corrections! Last question if you do not mind - the approach to measure memory usage from original post is OK or there is more precise/reliable way?

Comment: @DrYWit Uhm, sorry I don't know a lot about those topics. I would say _"no"_, since usually it would be better to use a proper profiling tool like **VisualVM** or **YourKit**; but you may want to open a new question for that or do a little bit of research.